# How do I reference a library on Android Studio?

Tags: android, compilation, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to build an [Xposed module](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial) but I'm stuck at referencing the library.

Library is inside app/lib because the ones in libs are included not referenced, my build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

configurations {
    provided
}

dependencies {
    provided 'lib/XposedBridgeApi-54.jar'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error:(20, 0) The description lib/XposedBridgeApi-54.jar is invalid
```

It looks like it can't find the library because if I try to change the name to something that doesn't exists it gives the same error.
I tried:

```
provided 'XposedBridgeApi-54.jar'
provided 'lib/XposedBridgeApi-54.jar'
provided 'app/lib/XposedBridgeApi-54.jar'
```

First one placing library in the root folder and nothing works.

This is how the directory structure looks (can't post pictures):

i.stack.imgur.com/jmN3B.png

[Official documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Referencing-a-Library) says to use:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:lib1')
}
```

but I don't know what to use with this format.

Comment: I solved using this instructions: [github](https://github.com/mallegonian/CleanLockscreen)
It adds xposed library as sdk add-on and then I need to change sdk target but I'd still like to know if there is another way to reference a lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for this checking other github repositories, looks like most of people don't use Android Studio.

The key is don't add anything on projectName/build.gradle but add at the end of projectName/app/src/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    provided files('lib/XposedBridgeApi-54.jar')
}
```

remember to not put it on libs

[Reference](https://github.com/xenon92/xposed-keep-trash)